# How to get text input data and pass it to email via linking - react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to pass whatever the user types into the TextInput, to send to email using linking.
I am using Expo and haven't come across anything that might do this.

```
export default class Completed extends Component {

state = {
          email: '',
       }
    
    
       handleEmail = (text) => {
          this.setState({ email: text })
       }
    
   render() {
        return ( 
    
    <View>
        <TextInput style={[styles.input, styles.pushUp]} 
        multiline
            placeholder={"Description"}>
        onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}
        </TextInput>
    
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description')}>
            <Text style={{color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}>NEXT</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
    
    </View>

    )

    }

    }
```

Comment: You may have to eject from Expo to achieve this.

Comment: I don't want to Eject at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
const MyTouchableOpacity  = ({ url, children }) => {
  const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
    // Checking if the link is supported for links with custom URL scheme.
    const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

    if (supported) {
      // Opening the link with some app, if the URL scheme is "http" the web link should be opened
      // by some browser in the mobile
      await Linking.openURL(url);
    } else {
      Alert.alert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`);
    }
  }, [url]);

  return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handlePress} />
};
```

and use it like this

```
<MyTouchableOpacity url={`mailto:${this.state.email}?subject=SendMail&body=Description`}>
  <Text style={{color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}>NEXT</Text>
</MyTouchableOpacity>
```

Based on doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: This won't work there is no reference to pass users text input

Comment: @Ding0: True, it is based on OPs version with hard-coded maito. Working on it.

Comment: Cheers, you put me on the right path. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure :-)